# Find the number of 3-cycles, i.e., permutations consisting of exactly one cycle of length 3, in $S_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the number of 3-cycles, i.e., permutations consisting of exactly one cycle of
length 3, in $S_4$.

---

4? feels like a statistics question

Comment: First note $(1 2 3) \neq (1 3 2)$ and consider how many choices you have for the three positions in the cycle. If the pattern is not obvious to you there are very few cases so brute force is an easy option as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you choose 3 distinct numbers from the set{1,2,3,4}. so there are 4.3.2/3!=4 numbers of way to choose 3 distinct numbers.now,as each element of a cycle can not go to the same element.so if we choose a element then there are remaining 2 many possibility for its image.so the next element has only one possible image.therefore from 3 elements we can get only two 3-cycle.so tota number of 3-cyclesl 4.2=8.